# Convert scalar type to complex type in OData

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, odata

I have following EF entity.

```
public class Order
{
    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }

    public bool Delivered { get { /* some logic involving OrderItems */ } }
}
```

I register it with OData like this:

```
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Order>("Orders");
```

My problem is that this "Delivered" isn't a field in database, but it is computed on the fly based on the statuses of the individual OrderItems. As such, it is an expensive field to compute so I'd like to include it only when client explicitly asks for it with "$expand=Delivered". If this expand isn't specified, then the property isn't included so it's not computed and the operation is cheap.

Unfortunately, this doesn't pass validation in the ODataController, it fails with:

```
Microsoft.OData.ODataException: 'Property 'Delivered' on type 'Gemalto.Sas.Authentication.Entities.UserDto' is not a navigation property or complex property. Only navigation properties can be expanded.'
```

Which kind of makes sense. Since I can't make it into navigation property, I tried to make it into complex type. If I understand this, complex type is "non scalar object without primary key". So I thought that just converting it into this will help:

```
public class Order
{
    ...

    public ComplexValue Delivered { get; set; }
}

public class ComplexValue
{
    public boolean Value { get { /* complex logic here ... */ } }
}
```

But ODataConventionModelBuilder still doesn't create it as a complextype but as normal property (confirmed via CSDL export). I also tried to explicitly call .ComplexType() on the builder, but that doesn't do anything (call succeeds though).

I feel like I'm missing something. Does anybody know how to achieve this?